# How do you air strafe to the right in team fortress 2?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-soldier

Playing as a soldier, air-strafing to the left is easy - all you need to do is shoot to the right, jump and hold the crouch button while turning left.

On the other hand, strafing to the right seems to mess up all the time. I suspect that this could be because the soldier's rocket launcher is on his right shoulder so shooting to the left in order to begin air strafing to the right is awkward.

Comment: I really doubt the developers would consider things like "right shoulder" that you're talking about. And there is a rocket launcher that is centered on the screen, isn't there? Looks more like a bug to me.

Comment: @BlaXpirit The soldier's rocket launchers do actually fire from his right shoulder. You're right about The Original though- it fires from the centre so may be worth a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to follow these steps:

1. Obtain a rocket launcher.
2. Jump and shoot directly behind you, downwards at a 45° angle
3. As soon as you fire, face forward and hold <kbd>D</kbd> while slowly moving your mouse to the right. *Do not press* <kbd>W</kbd>.
4. Enjoy the splendor of air strafing to the right

The trick with this one that requires practice is facing forward after shooting a rocket behind you. It's a fine art, but then again the entire practice of rocket jumping requires finesse.