# How do you get horizontal movement with a rocket jump?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-soldier

Both [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/108512/what-different-kinds-of-rocket-jumping-techniques-are-there) and [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/what-is-the-technique-for-effective-rocket-jumping) question provide good advice for various types of rocket-jumping, and I have followed these jumping techniques to the best of my ability, but there is one technique that continues to elude me as a solider.

Rapid forward momentum.

My rocket jumps carry a little forward momentum, but not nearly the map-crossing, spawn-killing, game-ruining techniques of legendary rocket jumpers.

What type of rocket-jumping can provide this tremendous forward momentum?  Specifically, I know that 'skipping' provides map-clearing capabilities, but what about the initial momentum-creating jump?  What are the ideal conditions for such a jump?

Comment: I usually fire at the wall while crouching. That seems to get me the farthest with a unique rocket launcher. To get around the map, I use a quick flick of my wrist to turn around and fire at the ground behind me as soon as I land.

Comment: @МикроПингвин You might want to add that as an answer, since it looks pretty complete, and there don't seem to be a flood of other answers incoming.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you air strafe to the right in team fortress 2?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132594/how-do-you-air-strafe-to-the-right-in-team-fortress-2)

Comment: @Neffer_23 I don't think so.  Though Air Strafing may offer an increase in horizontal movement, the other question doesn't explain that, nor does this question ask anything about air strafing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get vertical height, fire a rocket at the floor. If you want to get horizontal distance, fire a rocket at the wall. Crouch jumping amplifies the effect for both.

If you aim the rocket at about knee level on the wall, you'll give yourself the perfect angle to perform a couple speed pogos to gain even more momentum. Once you have this practiced, you'll be at the enemy's spawn gate in no time.

Comment: Why you only mentioned shooting a rocket at a wall? Gaining distance is certainly possible by shooting at ground. Only using walls greatly restricts the class' movement.

Answer (score 2):

I usually fire at the wall while crouching. That seems to get me the farthest with a unique rocket launcher. To get around the map, I use a quick flick of my wrist to turn around and fire at the ground behind me as soon as I land.